# Contractibility of X: Does X have to be homotopy equivalent to every one point subset of X, or just at least one

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For a space $X$ to be contractible, must it be homotopy equivalent to every one point subset of $X$, or must there just exist at least a one point subset of $X$ that is homotopy equivalent to $X$?

I assume it's the latter, as it makes more sense intuitively--but I just want to double check.

Comment: All one point spaces are homotopy equivalent, so if $X \simeq \{x_0\}$ for some $x_0 \in X$ then $X \simeq *$ for any one point space $*$. I suggest you revise what the terms homotopy equivalent and contractible really mean. It seems that you have some confusion around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. If $X$ can be contracted to $x_0$, i.e. there is a homotopy $h:[0,1]\times X\rightarrow X$ such that $h(0, x) = x$ and $h(1, x) = x_0$. In particular $X$ is path-connected, as $p_x(t) = h(t, x)$ is a path from $x$ to $x_0$. We only need to show $c_1(x) = x_1$ is homotopic to $c_0(x) = x_0$ for any $x_1\in X$. Indeed, $H(t, x) = p_{x_1}(t) = h(t, x_1)$ is a homotopy from $c_1$ to $c_0$.